# How to generate minified javascript with Script#?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, minify, script#

I am testing Script# and its manual tells me that it has a "Release" mode, where the code is minified for performance. But I couldn't find how to enter this mode. Anyone knows?

**Update** BenS has found a command line solution. I wonder if there is a graphical solution, preferably integrated with Visual Studio.

Comment: If a such a GUI feature exists it is undocumented. You should be able to set what compiler options are used within VS. Probably somewhere in the project build properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Script#'s author, [Nikhil Kothari's Script# Intro](http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharpIntro.aspx):

> The compiler has the notion of debug
>   and release builds.
>
> ssc /ref:sscorlib.dll
>   /ref:Script.ScriptFX.Core.dll
>   /minimize /out:HelloWorld.js
>   HelloWorld.cs
>
> Running the compiler without /debug
>   and with /minimize produces a release
>   build.

From the [Script# Manual](http://projects.nikhilk.net/Content/Projects/ScriptSharp/ScriptSharp.pdf) on page 8:

> The resulting Web site structure looks
>   like the following (as shown in the
>   screenshot of the solution explorer
>   below) with Script# assemblies present
>   in the Bin\Script folder and the
>   corresponding debug and release script
>   files within the App_Scripts folder.